# Run this program as an administrator (Or how to get the licence UAC Admin during the necessary moment)

Tags: delphi

It is the second attempt to receive the answer on a question. Very much I apologise, but my English very bad, therefore it is very difficult to me to explain that I want, especially in technical questions :_(

I try once again, this time with a concrete example, that it is necessary for me.

DelphiXe, Win7x64. Windows Uac is On. The user works with the rights of the Administrator.

The program (example) which should copy files from one place in another is given.
She should be started by usual way (not on behalf of the Admin). Therefore gluing to a manifes(*.rc) EXE-file (which grants the rights of the Admin - requests at start more truly) is not required.
Copying should be carried out by usual way - the rights of Admin should be requested only in case of need and without restart of the program.

Problem (in a code are marked "*"): 
1. How to define that Windows UAC is present at system and whether it is Enabled
2. How to get the licence of Admin right (to deduce message Windows UAC) only in case of need and actually to get this licence for the program not restarting it

Example - file managers 'Far manager' (or 'Total Commander') can so to do - they copy files at usual start (not on behalf of the Admin), and cause inquiry UAC only when business concerns system folders. Thus programs are not restarted and at first give out the prevention.

P.S. It is grateful for the help and editing of my posts.

### Program: Form, one button, opendialog, savedialog

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    OpenDialogFROM: TOpenDialog;
    Button1: TButton;
    SaveDialogTO: TSaveDialog;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    Function TestPathWrite(path:string):bool;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Function IsWindowsUAC_Enabled:bool; // Test Windows UAC turn on (*)
begin
Result:=false;
// ????
// How to define, whether function UAC is included in system - enabled (we will admit, that we work in OS is more senior XP)
end;

Function TurnOnAdminRight:bool; // To activate the rights of the Administrator to operation (*)
begin
Result:=false;
// ????
// How to activate message Windows UAC (approximately "To allow to make to this program changes to the computer?" or something similar)
// and to get the licence of the Administrator for this program?
end;

Function TForm1.TestPathWrite(path:string):bool;
var f:file;Err:integer;
begin
Result:=false;assignfile(f,IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(path)+'$$TestFile$$.tmp');
{$I-}
Rewrite(f);
{$I+}
Err:=IoResult;
If Err<>0 then begin
   if Err=5 then begin // Access denided
      if IsWindowsUAC_Enabled then // Windows UAC is ON
         if TurnOnAdminRight=True then TestPathWrite(path); // Repeated check, else exit whith error message
   end;
Showmessage('Error write to path: '+path+', Error: '+inttostr(Err));
Exit;
end;
CloseFile(f);Erase(f);Result:=true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
// Test procedure by which it can be demanded the rights of the Administrator
// It also could be record procedure in windows register or another by which the rights can be demanded, and can't be demanded
// The problem to request the rights (and to include) only when they are necessary

if OpenDialogFROM.Execute then if SaveDialogTO.Execute then
if FileExists(OpenDialogFROM.FileName)=true then
if TestPathWrite(ExtractfilePath(SaveDialogTO.FileName))=true then
if CopyFile(Pchar(OpenDialogFROM.FileName),Pchar(SaveDialogTO.FileName),true)=true then
Showmessage('File: '+OpenDialogFROM.FileName+' it is successfully copied as: '+SaveDialogTO.FileName);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
SaveDialogTo.Options:=[ofNoTestFileCreate,ofEnableSizing,ofDontAddToRecent]; // SaveDialog does not do check on record
end;

end.
```

Copying will be normal for example at

From d:\MyTest.txt in e:\MyNew.txt

And the message with inquiry of rights UAC should to appear for example at

From d:\MyTest.txt in c:\Windows\MyNew.txt

Comment: Really don't understand the question

Comment: Having read the linked post I have a suspician what's being asked here is "how do I make my app run elevated without using a manifest, COM object, or restarting the process"

Comment: His other questions are written perfectly well, so I'm voting this down as an encouragement for it to be rewritten, when I'll remove the vote.

Comment: -1 this question is very poorly phrased and cannot be confidently answered in this form. Please rephrase.

Comment: Ok. Plz, kill new: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814931/run-this-program-as-an-administrator-2-or-how-to-get-the-licence-uac-admin-durin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if UAC is active using this function

```
interface

uses
  Registry, SysUtils;

function IsUACActive: Boolean;

implementation

function IsUACActive: Boolean;
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Result := FALSE;

  // There's a chance it's active as we're on Vista or Windows 7. Now check the registry
  if CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
  begin
    Reg := TRegistry.Create;
    try
      Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

      if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System') then
      begin
        if (Reg.ValueExists('EnableLUA')) and (Reg.ReadBool('EnableLUA')) then
          Result := TRUE;
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(Reg);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

You can run an elevated process using the following function:

```
...

interface

uses
  Windows, ShellAPI, Forms;

type
  TExecuteFileOption = (
    eoHide,
    eoWait,
    eoElevate
  );
  TExecuteFileOptions = set of TExecuteFileOption;

function ExecuteFile(Handle: HWND; const Filename, Paramaters: String; Options: TExecuteFileOptions): Integer;

implementation

function ExecuteFile(Handle: HWND; const Filename, Paramaters: String; Options: TExecuteFileOptions): Integer;
var
  ShellExecuteInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  ExitCode: DWORD;
begin
  Result := -1;

  ZeroMemory(@ShellExecuteInfo, SizeOf(ShellExecuteInfo));
  ShellExecuteInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
  ShellExecuteInfo.Wnd := Handle;
  ShellExecuteInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;

  if (eoElevate in Options) and (IsUACActive) then
    ShellExecuteInfo.lpVerb := PChar('runas');

  ShellExecuteInfo.lpFile := PChar(Filename);

  if Paramaters <> '' then
    ShellExecuteInfo.lpParameters := PChar(Paramaters);

  // Show or hide the window
  if eoHide in Options then
    ShellExecuteInfo.nShow := SW_HIDE
  else
    ShellExecuteInfo.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;

  if ShellExecuteEx(@ShellExecuteInfo) then
    Result := 0;

  if (Result = 0) and (eoWait in Options) then
  begin
    GetExitCodeProcess(ShellExecuteInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);

    while (ExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE) and
          (not Application.Terminated) do
    begin
      sleep(50);

      GetExitCodeProcess(ShellExecuteInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);
    end;

    Result := ExitCode;
  end;
end;
```

To run an elevated, hidden process and wait for it to exit:

```
ExecuteFile(Self.Handle, 'Filename', 'Parameters', [eoHide, eoWait, eoElevate]);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 9):

I think you need to start *another* process with raised privileges (using a manifest...). Either this can be a separate EXE, or the same EXE (perhaps with some appropriate command-line argument).

Of course, to the end user, this will *look like* if the original process somehow 'magically' got raised privileges.

Comment: +1 That's what I ended up doing, too. I wrote about it [here](http://tondrej.blogspot.com/2007/06/datasnap-to-rescue.html).

Answer (score 4):

Once a process has started as at a user privilege level this process can't get admin privileges. This is necessary since the privilege level doubles as integrity level. So you need in some way start a new elevated process or communicate with an existing elevated process.

Answer (score 1):

The question is difficult to understand... since there is no question.

From what you wrote, I guess that you want to perform some actions which requires the Administrator **elavated** rights.

It's not enough to run as Adminitrator, to be able to execute all actions.

The UAC expects to **elevate** the current user rights, even if he/she is a local administrator, to perform some security-related actions.

Read [this technical article from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691%28WS.10%29.aspx) for step-by-step guidance about how the UAC works.