# Run this program as an administrator 2 (Or how to get the licence UAC Admin during the necessary moment)

Tags: delphi, uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run this program as an administrator (Or how to get the licence UAC Admin during the necessary moment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808016/run-this-program-as-an-administrator-or-how-to-get-the-licence-uac-admin-during)

It is the second attempt to receive the answer on a question: [Run this program as an administrator (Or how to get the licence UAC Admin during the necessary moment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808016/run-this-program-as-an-administrator)

Unfortunately I have not had time to edit the first question and a theme have closed.
Very much I apologise, but my English very bad, therefore it is very difficult to me to explain that I want, especially in technical questions :_(

I try once again, this time with a concrete example, that it is necessary for me.

DelphiXe, Win7x64. Windows Uac is On. The user works with the rights of the Administrator.

The program (example) which should copy files from one place in another is given.
She should be started by usual way (not on behalf of the Admin). Therefore gluing to a manifes(*.rc) EXE-file (which grants the rights of the Admin - requests at start more truly) is not required.
Copying should be carried out by usual way - the rights of Admin should be requested only in case of need and without restart of the program.

Problem (in a code are marked "*"): 
1. How to define that Windows UAC is present at system and whether it is Enabled
2. How to get the licence of Admin right (to deduce message Windows UAC) only in case of need and actually to get this licence for the program not restarting it

Example - file managers 'Far manager' (or 'Total Commander') can so to do - they copy files at usual start (not on behalf of the Admin), and cause inquiry UAC only when business concerns system folders. Thus programs are not restarted and at first give out the prevention.

P.S. It is grateful for the help and editing of my posts.

### Program: Form, one button, opendialog, savedialog

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    OpenDialogFROM: TOpenDialog;
    Button1: TButton;
    SaveDialogTO: TSaveDialog;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    Function TestPathWrite(path:string):bool;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Function IsWindowsUAC_Enabled:bool; // Test Windows UAC turn on (*)
begin
Result:=false;
// ????
// How to define, whether function UAC is included in system - enabled (we will admit, that we work in OS is more senior XP)
end;

Function TurnOnAdminRight:bool; // To activate the rights of the Administrator to operation (*)
begin
Result:=false;
// ????
// How to activate message Windows UAC (approximately "To allow to make to this program changes to the computer?" or something similar)
// and to get the licence of the Administrator for this program?
end;

Function TForm1.TestPathWrite(path:string):bool;
var f:file;Err:integer;
begin
Result:=false;assignfile(f,IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(path)+'$$TestFile$$.tmp');
{$I-}
Rewrite(f);
{$I+}
Err:=IoResult;
If Err<>0 then begin
   if Err=5 then begin // Access denided
      if IsWindowsUAC_Enabled then // Windows UAC is ON
         if TurnOnAdminRight=True then TestPathWrite(path); // Repeated check, else exit whith error message
   end;
Showmessage('Error write to path: '+path+', Error: '+inttostr(Err));
Exit;
end;
CloseFile(f);Erase(f);Result:=true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
// Test procedure by which it can be demanded the rights of the Administrator
// It also could be record procedure in windows register or another by which the rights can be demanded, and can't be demanded
// The problem to request the rights (and to include) only when they are necessary

if OpenDialogFROM.Execute then if SaveDialogTO.Execute then
if FileExists(OpenDialogFROM.FileName)=true then
if TestPathWrite(ExtractfilePath(SaveDialogTO.FileName))=true then
if CopyFile(Pchar(OpenDialogFROM.FileName),Pchar(SaveDialogTO.FileName),true)=true then
Showmessage('File: '+OpenDialogFROM.FileName+' it is successfully copied as: '+SaveDialogTO.FileName);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
SaveDialogTo.Options:=[ofNoTestFileCreate,ofEnableSizing,ofDontAddToRecent]; // SaveDialog does not do check on record
end;

end.
```

Copying will be normal for example at

From d:\MyTest.txt in e:\MyNew.txt

And the message with inquiry of rights UAC should to appear for example at

From d:\MyTest.txt in c:\Windows\MyNew.txt

Comment: Gu, add this explanation to your original question. This question is likely to become closed.

Comment: To me to alter my basic question?

Comment: Ok, Has altered. But it seems to me, that that question is closed and to answer it anybody any more will not be :(

Comment: Patience. If the question _is_ clear now, then the question will be reopened.

Comment: you already have the answer which is that the elevated tasks require a separate process

Comment: @gu Have you read the UAC topics on msdn?

Answer (score 3):

You can check if UAC is active using this function

```
interface

uses
  Registry, SysUtils;

function IsUACActive: Boolean;

implementation

function IsUACActive: Boolean;
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Result := FALSE;

  // There's a chance it's active as we're on Vista or Windows 7. Now check the registry
  if CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
  begin
    Reg := TRegistry.Create;
    try
      Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

      if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System') then
      begin
        if (Reg.ValueExists('EnableLUA')) and (Reg.ReadBool('EnableLUA')) then
          Result := TRUE;
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(Reg);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

You can run an elevated process using the following function:

```
...

interface

uses
  Windows, ShellAPI, Forms;

type
  TExecuteFileOption = (
    eoHide,
    eoWait,
    eoElevate
  );
  TExecuteFileOptions = set of TExecuteFileOption;

function ExecuteFile(Handle: HWND; const Filename, Paramaters: String; Options: TExecuteFileOptions): Integer;

implementation

function ExecuteFile(Handle: HWND; const Filename, Paramaters: String; Options: TExecuteFileOptions): Integer;
var
  ShellExecuteInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
  ExitCode: DWORD;
begin
  Result := -1;

  ZeroMemory(@ShellExecuteInfo, SizeOf(ShellExecuteInfo));
  ShellExecuteInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
  ShellExecuteInfo.Wnd := Handle;
  ShellExecuteInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;

  if (eoElevate in Options) and (IsUACActive) then
    ShellExecuteInfo.lpVerb := PChar('runas');

  ShellExecuteInfo.lpFile := PChar(Filename);

  if Paramaters <> '' then
    ShellExecuteInfo.lpParameters := PChar(Paramaters);

  // Show or hide the window
  if eoHide in Options then
    ShellExecuteInfo.nShow := SW_HIDE
  else
    ShellExecuteInfo.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;

  if ShellExecuteEx(@ShellExecuteInfo) then
    Result := 0;

  if (Result = 0) and (eoWait in Options) then
  begin
    GetExitCodeProcess(ShellExecuteInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);

    while (ExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE) and
          (not Application.Terminated) do
    begin
      sleep(50);

      GetExitCodeProcess(ShellExecuteInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);
    end;

    Result := ExitCode;
  end;
end;
```

To run an elevated, hidden process and wait for it to exit:

```
ExecuteFile(Self.Handle, 'Filename', 'Parameters', [eoHide, eoWait, eoElevate]);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: that registry check looks like it would fail on 64 bit windows. Also, why bother checking for UAC? Wouldn't you just run elevated no matter what for operations that needed it.

Comment: for winx64 use: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System, though also the first variant works normally. The second piece of a code demands program restart, it is not desirable. And without restart in any way it is impossible (as described Far or TC)?

Comment: @David, if the copy doesn't need, it then why be elevated? I think the question is sensible. It may copy files in My Documents most of the time and just sometimes need elevation.

Comment: @mj2008 I mean why check whether uac is active? Obviously you only elevate for operations that need it. I suppose you only should attempt to elevate if uac is enabled and it's a standard user. I can't believe you need registry to check uac.

Comment: @Gu "The second piece of a code demands program restart, it is not desirable." A process can only acquire an elevated token at startup. With this knowledge you should see that it is essential to start a new process in order for some aspects of functionality to run elevated. Why have you not read the MSDN documents on UAC which explain all this? Do you need help in finding them?

Comment: Whereas it does Far or Total commander? We start as usually, we copy files and as soon as business concerns system folders - directly in the course of copying there is at first a prevention of the file manager, and then message Windows UAC and at the consent copying is made. Otherwise process gets the licence UAC directly in the course of work, without restart. How it to realise?